# Mathematical Notation for Graph Properties

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I have a graph with two sets, vertices and edges, $G=(V,E)$. In my case every vertex and every edge have some attributes like $type$.

What is the mathematical correct way to get the value of a vertex' property? Maybe $property(v)$ where $property$ is the property name and $v$ the single vertex?

What is the correct way to get only the vertices (a set of vertices) that have a specific value? For example if I want a set of vertices that only have $1$ as the value of $type$?

Comment: How about defining a function $p : V  \to S$, where $S$ is a set of values?

Comment: As an example of Rodrigo de Azevedo 's comment, the color of a  node is typically defined by the function $c:V\rightarrow \{1,\cdots, |V| \}$.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of defining a function and the example of coloring. This helps a lot. But the second question still remains, how to address a set where all the elements have $p(v) = 1$?.

Comment: @ScientiaEtVeritas You said it yourself: "a set where all the elements have $p(v) = 1$", in notation, is $\{v: v \in V, p(v) = 1\}$